# How to modify SharePoint online's new design for all document library and lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, office-365

I want to change SharePoint online's new design of document library and lists.

i have modified all master pages but didn't get any result.

The following view i want to change.
[image]

Is there any way to change this view for all list and libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment Microsoft does not allow any branding or injecting script in the Modern Experiences.

Vote for  change: https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/13385364-allow-javascript-customization-and-css-branding-th

The only way you can make changes is by using a Browser plugin like [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe),
but to implement that across a Company requires configuration of every (user) Browser. IE takes some more effort than Chrome or Firefox. As far as I know there is no Extension for Microsoft Edge.

Answer (score 0):

1. Choose Admin centers and then SharePoint
2. Choose Settings.
3. Next to SharePoint Lists and Libraries experience, select either Classic experience or New experience (auto-detect).

[image]

[support.office](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-the-default-experience-for-lists-or-document-libraries-from-new-or-classic-66dac24b-4177-4775-bf50-3d267318caa9?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

**Note**: You can change the look and feel when you work on classic mode only, New experrience does not support jquery/css modification. [support article](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/13385364-allow-javascript-customization-and-css-branding-th).

Comment: i want new experience with list and libraries view customization. is it possible?